# How do I get JSDoc parse functional components in my React app?

Tags: reactjs, jsdoc

I have a bigger React app and I try to document it using JSdoc.

I have one class component in there which gets properly parsed. The class JSDoc block as well as each class method. However on functional components, which are all other components, it fails to parse them at all.

It parses the JSDoc block at the top of each component but does not go into the function to parse JSDoc blocks on each function within the functional components nor on the hooks.

On each functional component it fails to recognize JSXFragments, debug reporting an error:

```
DEBUG: Found a node with unrecognized type JSXFragment. Ignoring the node and its descendants.
```

I tried several attempts using `@returns {JSX.Element}` and `@returns {ReactNode}`.

I found one blog article saying that they went with completely function free components doing all logic in Redux. However I don't use Redux, I do everything using useContext. This has historical reasons and I rather don't want to refactor the whole project with Redux or even useReducer just to get JSDoc working.

```
JSDoc 4.0.2 (Sun, 19 Feb 2023 23:01:18 GMT)
```

jsdoc.json

```
{
  "source": {
    "include": ["src", "src/components", "src/context"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "dist"]
  },
  "plugins": [
    "plugins/markdown"
  ],
  "opts": {
    "template": "./node_modules/minami",
    "destination": "./docs",
    "encoding": "utf8"
  },
  "templates": {
    "cleverLinks": true,
    "monospaceLinks": true
  },
  "jsx": {
    "pragma": "JSX"
  }
}
```

Comment: I personally went through a similar experience of learning about jsdoc (the tool) and found similar frustrations. My sense is that jsdoc the format is great but jsdoc the tool is not (anymore?). I've since settled on documentation.js instead which relies on the same jsdoc annotations and it's working well for me so far.

Comment: @ChristianFritz thanks for the hint I will check that out.